# siunitx does not detect math font correctly

Tags: fonts, siunitx

The following MWE resembles the structure of my thesis:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[minionint,lf]{MinionPro}
\usepackage[sansmath,lf]{MyriadPro}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit{\Electronmass}{\text{\ensuremath{m_{0}}}}

\begin{document}

{
\mathversion{sans}
\sffamily
\begin{align}
    m = \si{\Electronmass} \\
    m = \SI{1.5}{\nano\meter}
\end{align}
}

\end{document}
```

If I compile it, the result looks like this:

[image]

`siunitx` detects the font which can be seen at the second line. However, the first line shows my problem, both `m` in that line should look identical. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Just a heads up: you are using `align` in your MWE without loading `amsmath`, which makes it not compilable. Also, you are not using the alignment capability of `align`, so a `gather` may be better suited.

Comment: Why do you use `\text{\ensuremath{}} in your unit definition? This looks like you want the `m` if the electron mass to be math, but then turn it into text mode. Maybe that is why the result is not what you expect. By the way, if I use the `arevmath` package (without using MinionPro and yriadPro) I do get a sansserif `m_0` with your MWE.

Comment: @ph0t0nix if you look in the siunitx code the symbol for the speed of light is defined in the same way (clight)